# How to describe a character who is sick from trauma?

Tags: fiction, character-development

I would just like symptoms and/or adjectives about a character when they might suddenly get sick because of a traumatic experience.

I just don't know how to describe the character and this is a vital part of my story. She is actually getting her mind touched by a demon and that will cause some serious shock, if not PTSD. The "presence" sticks around and she doesn't get the PTSD until the very end, but it's still a serious shock for her.

The shock is not immediate, but it shows on her face and through physical symptoms. Not having a real-world illness to draw from, though, I'm unsure of what those symptoms may be, or how to show her discomfort.

Comment: Hi INR! Welcome to Writing.SE! Please take a look at our [tour] and [help] pages, you might find them helpful. I'm afraid your question is rather off topic for us: in essence, you're asking what to write. Also, your question is rather broad: there are many kinds of "sick". We can help you with the *how* - language, techniques, tropes, etc., we can help you with how to find relevant information, but the *what* to write is up to you. Perhaps you can [edit] your question to make it something we can answer?

Comment: Hi INR, I saw you have edited your question and I voted to reopen, but it will take a few votes. In the meantime, some words that might help us understand your question: Psychosomatic, PTSD, Trauma, Shock, Anxiety, Nausea… If you told us a little about how it needs to work dramatically (is he just anxious or is he non-functional)...

Answer (score 4):

The characteristics of being sick would depend heavily on what type of sickness this character has. A runny nose is common with a cold, where as they might be excreting from more places than just the nose if they had dysentery... (sorry, haha). WebMD, though unreliable if you're actually trying to diagnose yourself, would provide all the common symptoms for whatever you want your character to be sick with.

Additionally, you've probably been sick at some point in your life. Describe how you felt during that time.

Comment: Thanks, the character is just getting over a traumatic experience and is sick because of that experience. IF you have anymore tips I would love to hear them

Comment: @INR Most people will have many different reactions to overcoming/recovering from a traumatic experience, so it's up to you to know how your character will react. The only tips I can give you without actually writing your character description for you (which this site is not for) is this: try looking at WebMD or Googling various coping mechanisms according to the experience your character went through.